# JavaFX: Create EventHandler

Tags: events, javafx

I'm writting an event handler for a button, on the net I saw a lot of codes like this:

```
b = new Button("click me");
    b.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        /*
            calling several oblects' methods and doing things
        */
        }
    });
```

If I have a method like `setGUI` and I must create several buttons and several `eventhandlers`, the question is: is it ok to put a lot of "action" there? If I have 10 `buttons` and every button has an `event handler` then my `setGUI` will be like 500 lines long, maybe even more. I tried to create an event handler object in this way:

```
public class MyListener implements EventHandler{
@override
public void handle(Event event) {
        //My code
    }
}
```

But EventHandler is Abstract and I have to implement several methods.
Googling I saw this code:

```
public class AppWithEvents1 extends Application {
    Text text=null;
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        text=new Text(10,50,"Non hai mai cliccato ");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Click me");
        Listener a=new Listener(this);
        btn.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, a);
        Group root = new Group(btn);
        root.getChildren().add(text);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public void updateText(int n){
        text.setText("Hai cliccato "+n
        +" volte");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

and he created this class:

```
class Listener
    implements EventHandler{
        AppWithEvents1 awe=null;
        int counter=0;
        Listener(AppWithEvents1 a){
            awe=a;
        }
    public void handle(Event t) {
        awe.updateText(++counter);
    }
}
```

Why didn't he implement all abstract methods?

Comment: `EventHandler` only has one abstract method (`handle(...)`). See [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html).

Comment: I got it, I was using `EventHandler` instead of `EventHandler<T>`. By he way is it better to create a listener or to write code directly in `btn.onMouseClicked()...` ?

Comment: @bogALT That depends. Can you reuse the code of the listeners somewhere? Is it beneficial for code readability? Do you need access to local variables/members not visible to other classes? Do you need access to members of the listener class other than the `handle` method? BTW: In java 8 you can also use lambda expressions instead of anonymus classes, which allows you to further reduce the amount of code.

Comment: yes, I would like to use several external objects and methods and all objects I create must be accessible by other objects outside the `setGUI` method